# How many eligible bachelors in a city?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, classification, data-mining

This is a very simple question posed to me by a friend of mine. I know it's a statistical analysis problem, but I suck at math.

Given the total population of $x$ within a metropolitan area, what would be the formula to determine approximately how many single heterosexual men or women there are between age($\min$) and age($\max$)?

Now as a secondary goal, how would you go about factoring in/out other relationship qualifications (such as education, employment status, etc.) from that subset of people?

I am sure there are standard tools statisticians use to solve problems like this. Please explain the algorithm, bearing in mind that if you use anything more than basic algebra you'll probably lose me :-)

Comment: I think that xkcd had a panel on the question some time ago.

Comment: Got a link? I'd like to read that

Comment: I'm at work, and want to be cautious about what keywords I search for.  *blush*

Comment: I believe he's referring to [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/314/). Anyways, this sounds like a good candidate for Fermi estimation.

Comment: A key word to look for within the xkcd site is Fermi.